# How to add multiple horizontalScrollViews dynamically

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

I want to add multiple horizontalscrollView to a linear layout dynamically. For this I have a linearLayout with id mainList. and an xml with horizontalScrollLayout as below. Its not working. What is the write way.

```
mainListView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainList);
hrscroll = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.hrscroll);
// hrtxt=(TextView) findViewById(R.id.hrtxt);
for(int i=0;i<categories.length;i++) {
    mainListView.addView(hrscroll);
}
```

XML for horizontalScrollLayout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<HorizontalScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/hrscroll"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</HorizontalScrollView>
```

Comment: you can not add same layout again and again.

Comment: But I want to show images sliding one below another categorie wize.How can I do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding `HorizontalScrollView` Dynamically to the `LinearLayout`

```
mainListView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainList);
// Creating mHorizontalScrollView array for multiple Categories
HorizontalScrollView[] mHorizontalScrollView = new HorizontalScrollView[categories.length];
for(int i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
    mHorizontalScrollView[i] = new HorizontalScrollView(context);
    mainListView.addView(mHorizontalScrollView[i]);
}
```

**Updated Answer :**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/mainListView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp" >

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/categoryOne"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/categoryTwo"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/categoryThree"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/categoryFour"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/categoryFive"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/categorySix"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:id="@+id/categorySeven"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**Activity File :**

Binding XML Views :

```
mainListView = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainList);
categoryOne = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.categoryOne);
categoryTwo = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.categoryTwo);
categoryThree = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.categoryThree);
categoryFour = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.categoryFour);
categoryFive = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.categoryFive);
categorySix = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.categorySix);
categorySeven = (HorizontalScrollView) findViewById(R.id.categorySeven);
```

Comment: Does your categories are predefined or they are dynamic generates.?

Comment: Then why you are adding HorizontalScrollView here just add it in XML itself inside LinearLayout and bind it in Java. How many categories you have?

Comment: 7 categories. for now I have kept them in XML. Later if this works I want to put them in a JSON file and keep it on server. No of categories may change.

Comment: @Manasi check Updated answer. This will work for you but it will create issue when you'll have dynamic categories from server for Dynamic Categories the above answer will work

Comment: Ur HorizontalScrolView array worked. Thanx. I have edited working code in my question

Comment: @Manasi you should not add working code to the question as user can see answers below question so no need to add working code with question. You can edit my answer and append your code. Editing your question.